# Kак связать устройство CD/DVDROM c назначенной буквой по HDEVINFO и SP_DEVINFO_DATA

Tags: winapi

Необходимо получить параметры CD-ROM (имя, производителя и т.д.). С получением этих параметров отлично справляется код:

```
HDEVINFO hDevInfo = NULL;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
hDevInfo = ::SetupDiGetClassDevs(
    NULL,
    0, 
    0,
    DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES
);
if(hDevInfo != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof( SP_DEVINFO_DATA );
    for(int i = 0; ::SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo( hDevInfo, i, &DeviceInfoData ); i++)
    {   
    // получаем для класса CDROM все необходимые локализованные параметры, кроме буквы диска
    }
}
```

Как получить букву диска устройства?
Букву CD/DVD-ROM можно получить с помощью `GetLogicalDriveStrings`, `GetDriveType`
Но как связать устройство с назначенной буквой?

Answer (score 0):

Как я решил данный вопрос:

```
GetLogicalDriveStrings - получение букв всех дисков
GetDriveType - поиск CD/DVD-ROM
SetupDiGetClassDevs, SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo - поиск девайсов по классу "CDROM"
RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\MountedDevices" .....
RegQueryValueEx( hKey, L"\\DosDevices\\буква CD/DVD-ROM
```

приведение devces_id из реестра и полученный из `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` к единому формату для соотнесения буквы и девайса.

Пишите, если есть более изящное решение.